# MultiInput token is not showing

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm using suggestion rows and suggestion columns. After selecting the suggestion. The token is not set to the field.

I've tried to setToken() method but still got error.

```
        this._oMultiInput = new MultiInput({
                valueHelpOnly: false,
                valueHelpRequest: this._onValueHelpRequested.bind(this),
                showSuggestion: true,
                suggestionColumns: [
                            new sap.m.Column({
                        header: new sap.m.Label({
                            text: "ID"
                        })
                    }),
                    new sap.m.Column({
                        header: new sap.m.Label({
                            text: "{customI18n>productNameLabel}"
                        })
                    })
                ],
                tokens: new sap.m.Token({key:"{masterData>Name}"})
            });

            this._oMultiInput.bindSuggestionRows({
                path: 'masterData>/SH_MerchandiseHierarchySet',
                template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                    cells: [
                        new sap.m.Label({
                            text: "{masterData>ExternalId}"
                        }),
                        new sap.m.Label({
                            text: "{masterData>Name}"
                        })
                    ]
                }).clone()
            });
```

To set the token in the field.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is that tokens need a text:
tokens: new sap.m.Token({text: "{masterData>Name}", key:"{masterData>Name}"})

Answer (score 0):

It goes on error beacause there isn't a method setToken()

Please you must refer only to ufficial documentation. [Here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.68.1/#/api/sap.m.Token) you can see all action/method/properties etc. of sap.m.Token